# Who are the stakeholders and what are their key drivers?

Tags: architecture

Currently, I'm doing my masters in Computing Science and I'm working on a project in which I have to analyze the Bitcoin repository. I have a bit of trouble in identifying the stakeholders for the repository, so maybe anyone of you can help me?

A list of stakeholders (so far):

- The people that use the Bitcoin blockchain (users).

And a list of negative stakeholders (so far):

- The authorities, as system is anonymous.
- The banks, as their number of transactions will decrease (in a perfect world, everyone uses cryptocurrency)

Secondly, to obtain a list of the key drivers of the system. I would like to now what the concerns of every stakeholder are. Example of concerns are: Security, Reliability, Performance, Extensibility, Efficiency and Adaptability.

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Comment: This is off topic I think as this pertains to economics and not directly to the Bitcoin technology which knows nothing of the "Bitcoin repository" or "negative steak holders". Maybe economics would give better answer. Yes it probably does require knowledge of how Bitcoin works but that is just a nitch in the economic question you have asked.

Comment: Also I would wager miners were only real stake holders until now that it has become more used by general public as an investment security.

Comment: You can make  distinction between users who merely receive and spend bitcoins and users who have put a substantial amount of money into long term-storage in the blockchain. In other words, among the users you can distinguish between investors and those who use it as a daily currency.

Comment: There are two concerns: 1) Volatile Bitcoin value 2) Banks are scared of Bitcoin.